# Getting Player Heads MCPE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you get player heads using commands in MCPE? Like get your own head and be able to place it down and all that cool stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now you cannot get custom player heads in MCPE and can only get custom player heads in Java edition.